# What kind of damage is a Parrot speaking Loshen Hara?

Tags: torts-damages

A parrot learns the phrase "Mary had a little lamb" and repeats it on Yom Kippur, making people think Mary broke her fast, embarrassing her.

Which of the four kinds of damages is it?
Is it even a damage?
Can the parrot be muad for speaking Loshen Hara?

It seems like Parrots mimic sounds for social reasons. They feel like they are part of a greater family when they do it. So they get pleasure from speaking (and being spoken back to)

Comment: If a person speaks only English ,and repeats loshon hara in Spanish but doesn't understand what he is saying ,and doesn't know its loshon hara. Did he violate LH?

Comment: @sam the question isn't if the parrot violated lashon hara; it's if the owner is liable for damages (like an ox goring)

Comment: This is clearly g'rama (i.e. indirect, not guaranteed damage) at best...

Comment: Replace the parrot with a small child greeting a house guest: "Mommy, is this the lady you said talks forever and never leaves?". Is the mother liable for lashon hara?

Comment: Liable for speaking the Loshen Hara to a child but wont not be liable for embarrassment because shoteh, katan, cheresh are not chayiv for damages. (Unless you hold that lashon Hara is like a fire.)

Comment: Would this be different than a case of an animal that bites someone and rips their clothing in the process which then causes them embarrassment? It’s all a situation of an animal causing boshes, for which the owner is not liable

Answer (score 4):

Even a human does not pay anything for lashon hara, it is not one of the *5* damages one pay because it is grama.

Source:
[2:7 משנה תורה, הלכות חובל ומזיק](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_One_Who_Injures_a_Person_or_Property.2.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)

> הַמַּבְעִית חֲבֵרוֹ אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁחָלָה מִן הַפַּחַד הֲרֵי זֶה פָּטוּר מִדִּינֵי אָדָם וְחַיָּב בְּדִינֵי שָׁמַיִם. וְהוּא שֶׁלֹּא נָגַע בּוֹ אֶלָּא כְּגוֹן שֶׁצָּעַק מֵאֲחוֹרָיו אוֹ שֶׁנִּתְרָאָה [לוֹ] בָּאֲפֵלָה וְכַיּוֹצֵא בָּזֶה. וְכֵן אִם צָעַק בְּאָזְנוֹ וְחֵרְשׁוֹ פָּטוּר מִדִּינֵי אָדָם וְחַיָּב בְּדִינֵי שָׁמַיִם

> A person who scares a colleague - even if the fright causes him to fall ill - is not liable according to the judgments of an earthly court; he does, however, have a moral and spiritual obligation to compensate him.

And even if it was not, animals don't make owner pay only nezek (damage), not boshet (shame).

Source:[Bava Kama 34:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Kamma.34b.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> כיצד שורו שבייש פטור והוא שבייש חייב

> How so? If his ox caused a person humilation, he is exempt from paying compensation, but if he himself humiliated another, he is liable.

Comment: Adding how you this will make your answer more believable by those of us who don't know you.